# OpenSearch Range Query Between Two Times

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

I have the following `hours` field defined in my AWS opensearch cluster:

```
{
  "close": 1200,
  "day": "monday",
  "open": 900
},
{
  "close": 1700,
  "day": "monday",
  "open": 1300
}
```

I'm trying to solve the query problem where it DOES NOT return the result if the time is say, 1230.

I'm using the following query, but it unfortunately is still returning the document (Like it's performing an OR on the two entires in hours array. How do I make it so both properties MUST match in a single item in the array?

Note: I've tried using the minimum_should_match below the must, but it returns 0 results for all queries, even within the open/close times.

```
GET hc_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "hours.open": {
              "lte": 1230
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "hours.close": {
              "gte": 1230
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10
}
```

Edit: The nested mapping is here:

```
hours: {
    include_in_root: true,
    type: "nested",
    properties: {
        open: {
            type: "short"
        },
        close: {
            type: "short"
        },
        day: {
            index: false,
            type: "text"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please share the mapping?

Comment: Sure, added above

Comment: i cannot reproduce your problem. Here's a gist with the set up + query you provided, and the response I got back https://gist.github.com/glenacota/94074038ece0f3dcac5f60cb3cd0dd28 Am I missing anything?

Comment: Thanks for your response. As I mentioned above, I want it to NOT return the result. Since the "open" hours do not include 12:30 (as shown in the example above), I'm trying to build a query where if "1230" is passed in, a result is not returned (because the business is closed between 1200-1300, as shown but the entries in the array).

Comment: oh, now i get it, let me answer to that

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using the `range` field type ([docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/range.html)).

For example, your mapping could become something like:

```
PUT your_index_name
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "hours": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "opening_hours": {
            "type": "integer_range"
          },
          "day": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then, your doc would look like something like:

```
POST your_index_name/_doc
{
  "hours": [
    {
      "opening_hours": {
        "gte": 900,
        "lt": 1200
      },
      "day": "monday"
    },
    {
      "opening_hours": {
        "gte": 1300,
        "lt": 1700
      },
      "day": "monday"
    }
  ]
}
```

And now you could query it as:

```
GET your_index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "hours",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "hours.opening_hours": {
            "value": 1230
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you can also use `date_range` types, instead of integers.